# JS Image Load Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

The load time for this site on mobile and laptop is very slow, how can I improve the performance of the JavaScript?

http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/8YK2n/embedded/result/

```
 Gallery = {
            _config: {
                speed: 500,
                size: 65,
                lightbox: !0,
                closeOnEsc: !0,
                animation: "default",
                slideshow: !1,
                slideshow_speed: 3E3,
                cube_speed: 1E3
            },
```

Comment: too many images. cache them client side.

Answer (score 0):

Get this plug-in for Firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/yslow/

You can run a report on your site and find out some great information that will help you diagnose the issue.

*update*
Yes, there appears to be a YSlow for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yslow/ninejjcohidippngpapiilnmkgllmakh?hl=en

However, I didn't actually click the link earlier - totally my bad. You have a signification amount of animation going on with those cubes (and melonJS looks awesome!). YSlow will be helpful in a general sense. However, you are probably running into the limits of the computer's CPU/video card. My next suggestion is to try profiling the application. In the Chrome menu, go to View -> Developer -> Javascript Console. Then go to the Profiles tab and try the various profiling options. This will show you where all the CPU resources are being taken up and might give you some ideas of where to focus your attention on.

Their site, http://www.melonjs.org/, has a forum. I hate to divert traffic from Stack Overflow, but if you post your question there, you may find responses from people who are more versed specifically in melonJS. There's no melonjs tag at Stack Overflow yet, so their experts don't seem to be lurking around here unfortunately.

Best of luck!

Comment: is there any thing for chrome